# How do I join multiple coroutine Consumers with a single Producer in PureScript?

Tags: coroutine, purescript

I'm think I'm starting to understand Coroutine producers and consumers, but I'm having the hardest time putting consumers and produces together in useful ways.  If I have this producer of `APIEvent`...

```hs
type ID = String

data APIEvent
  = Connecting
  | Fail String
  | Success String

derive instance gAPIEvent :: Generic APIEvent
instance showPeerEvent :: Show APIEvent where show = gShow

getID :: Producer APIEvent (Aff (avar :: AVAR, console :: CONSOLE, random :: RANDOM)) (Maybe ID)
getID = produceAff (\emit -> do
  i <- liftEff $ randomInt 0 10
  if i < 9
    then do
      -- If producer was called with `loop`, the
      -- producer will restart.
      emit $ Left $ Fail "Failure to get id."
      emit $ Right Nothing
    else do
      emit $ Left $ Success "id"
      emit $ Right $ Just "id"
  )
```

How would I connect it to two consumers that do system logging and basic
output, e.g.

```hs
logFailures :: Consumer APIEvent (Aff (avar :: AVAR, console :: CONSOLE, random :: RANDOM)) ID
logFailures = forever $ do
  event <- await
  lift $ do
    case event of
      (Fail message) -> log $ "LOG: " <> message

showOutput :: Consumer APIEvent (Aff (avar :: AVAR, console :: CONSOLE, random :: RANDOM)) ID
showOutput = forever $ do
  event <- await
  lift $ do
    log $ "STDOUT: " <> (show event)
```

I've tried using `joinConsumers`, but that creates a consumer of
(`Tuple APIEvent APIEvent`) instead of just `APIEvent`s, so then
it doesn't type check.

```hs
main = launchAff $ do
  v <- runProcess $
        (joinConsumers logFailures showOutput)
        `pullFrom` (loop getPeerID)
  log $ "Process result: " <> (show v)
```

Edit:

This is what I ended up with.

```
main = launchAff $ do
  v <- runProcess $
    transformConsumer
      (forever $ transform (\i -> Tuple i i))
      (joinConsumers logFailures showOutput)
    `pullFrom` (loop getID)
  log $ "Process result: " <> (show v)
```

Outputs...

```
LOG: Failure to get id.
STDOUT: Test.SO.Fail "Failure to get id."
LOG: Failure to get id.
STDOUT: Test.SO.Fail "Failure to get id."
STDOUT: Test.SO.Success "id"
Process result: "id"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've noticed, you can use `joinConsumers` to combine two `Consumer`s into a `Consumer` of `Tuple`s. So now you just need a way to change a `Consumer` of `Tuple a a` into a regular `Consumer` of `a`.

You can do this by using the `transformConsumer` function, which transforms a `Consumer` using a `Transformer`:

```
transformConsumer 
  :: forall i o f m a
   . (MonadRec m, Parallel f m)
  => Transformer i o m a
  -> Consumer o m a
  -> Consumer i m a
```

But how to create the `Transformer` there? Well, you can create one from a regular function using the `transform` function:

```
transform
  :: forall m i o
   . Monad m
  => (i -> o)
  -> Transformer i o m Unit
```

The function type you need is `a -> Tuple a a`, so `\a -> Tuple a a` will do the job.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  In my example I have the producer returning `ID`, and the only reason I have `ID` on the consumers is so the types line up.  I didn't see one, but is there a function similar to `transform` that returns `Transformer i o m a` instead of `Transformer i o m Unit`?  This doesn't work, but I feel like I need something like `(transformConsumer (liftFreeT $ Transform \i -> (Tuple (Tuple i i) pure)) (joinConsumers ...` where the second element of the tuple is the value yielded by the producer.

Comment: Well, `forever (transform f)` would have that type, but I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Actually, that is what I need!  Basically, I need the consumers to only listen and never yield a value, so the producer will be one to end the process and yield the `ID`.